# generates a new matrix with size (2n+1)×n by interpolating rows in C

Tags: c, matrix

Task:
Write a C program which, once an n×n matrix of real values has been read in, generates a new matrix with size (2n+1)×n, in which the n-1 additional rows are obtained by interpolating the original ones. More specifically, between any two consecutive rows of the loaded matrix, a new row must be inserted, whose elements are given by the arithmetic average of the corresponding values immediately above and below them.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

float m[n][n] = {{2.6,  4.4,  5.0},{4.8,  3.4,  7.2},{2.0,  2.6,  3.8}};
int i,j,k;

for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<n; j++) {
        printf("%.1f  ",m[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
printf("\n");

for (i=0, j=0; i<(2*n-1); i++) {
    if (i==0) {
        for (k=i; k<1; k++) {
            for (j=0; j<n; j++) {
                m[k][j] = m[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    if (i % 2 != 0 && i != 0) {
        for (k=i+1; k<n; k++) {
            for (j=0; j<n; j++) {
                m[k][j] = m[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    if (i % 2 == 0 && i != 0){
        for (k=i*2; k<(2*n - 1); k++) {
            for (j=0; j<n; j++) {
                m[k][j] = m[i][j];
            }
        }
        printf("\n\n");
    }
}

for (k=0; k<(2*n - 1); k++) {
    for (j=0; j<n; j++) {
        if (k % 2 != 0 ) {
            m[k][j] = ((m[k - 1][j] + m[k + 1][j]) / 2);
            printf("%.1f  ",m[k][j]);
            m[k][j] = 0;
        }
        else if (k % 2 == 0){
            printf("%.1f  ",m[k][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}

printf("\n\n\n");
return 0;
}
```

the output must be like this:

```
given the matrix:
2.6  4.4  5.0
4.8  3.4  7.2
2.0  2.6  3.8
the matrix to be computed and displayed is then:
2.6  4.4  5.0
3.7  3.9  6.1
4.8  3.4  7.2
2.4  3.0  5.5
2.0  2.6  3.8
```

but i ma getting this:

```
2.6  4.4  5.0  
3.7  3.9  6.1  
4.8  3.4  7.2  
4.8  3.4  7.2  
4.8  3.4  7.2
```

Comment: `(2n+1)×n` --> `(2n-1)×n`

Comment: `for (i=0, j=0; i<(2*n-1); i++) {` ... `m[k][j] = m[i][j];` : index `i` out of range.

Answer (score 0):

```
float m[n][n] = {{2.6,  4.4,  5.0},{4.8,  3.4,  7.2},{2.0,  2.6,  3.8}};
float new_m[2*n-1][n];
int i,j;

//copy
for(i=0;i<n;++i)
    memcpy(new_m[2*i], m[i], sizeof(m[i]));
//interpolating,
for(i=1;i<2*n-1;i+=2)
    for(j=0;j<n;++j)
        new_m[i][j] = (new_m[i-1][j] + new_m[i+1][j])/2.0;
//print
for(i=0;i<2*n-1;++i){
    for(j=0;j<n;++j)
        printf("%.1f ", new_m[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
}
```